# Get list of tags from SpaCy

Tags: python, spacy

Does SpaCy provide a way to get a list of POS tags? For example, I can write the following code:

```
test1 = "The brown fox is pretty."
doc1 = nlp(test1)
for word in doc1:
    print(word.tag_)
```

This code generates the following output:

```
DT
JJ
NN
VBZ
JJ
.
```

I would like to get a list like this:

```
["DT","JJ","NN","VBZ","JJ","."]
```

I can obviously write code to create the list, but that seems inefficient to do every time. I expected that SpaCy provides an easy way to get the list, but so far I have not been able to find an example or figure it out. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is `tags = [word.tag_ for word in doc]` really so inefficient?

Comment: Hi krisograbek, That code is not inefficient, except if SpaCy happens to already have a list in its model then I wouldn't need to create my own for every piece of text I'm evaluating in a huge amount of text. If there is nothing in SpaCy, then your code is exactly what I'd need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding extraction of tag list as a part of the pipeline and create [extensions](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes)
at Doc level.
I don't know if that would be more efficient in terms of performance but you will be able to access the tags using that extension.

Perhaps something like this,
**Code:**

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
def tag_list_component(doc):
    tags = [token.tag_ for token in doc]
    doc.set_extension('tags_', default=False, force=True)
    doc._.tags_ = tags
    
    return doc

if(nlp.has_pipe("tag_list_pipe")):
    nlp.remove_pipe("tag_list_pipe")
nlp.add_pipe(tag_list_component, name="tag_list_pipe")

doc = nlp("This is sparta!")
print(doc._.tags_)
doc = nlp("Brown fox is pretty!")
print(doc._.tags_)
```

**Output:**

```
['DT', 'VBZ', 'NNP', '.']
['NNP', 'NN', 'VBZ', 'JJ', '.']
```